# How to display completed print jobs with source URL

Tags: 14.04, command-line, printing

In the "view queue" GUI of my printer, I can click "show all completed jobs" and get the columns

```
Job|User|Document|Printer|Size|Time Submitted|Status
```

I hunted around for some way of doing this in the terminal and got close to what I wanted but not quite. When I execute `lpstat -W completed`, I get

```
HP-LaserJet-9050-121    alex             94208   Mon 06 Apr 2015 05:52:10 PM EDT
HP-LaserJet-9050-122    alex            160768   Mon 06 Apr 2015 05:53:14 PM EDT
HP-LaserJet-9050-123    alex             44032   Mon 06 Apr 2015 05:53:32 PM EDT
```

While this sort of does the job, I do need the "Document" column equivalent. I am wondering if there is a way to do this specifically from the terminal?

Edit:The "Document" column displays the title of the prints

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The directory `/var/log/cups` contains all the logs and `page_log` contains the information you need.  Depending on your log rotation and how far in the past you want to be able to do this, it'll take a:

```
cat /var/log/cups/page_log
```

or for just the LaserJet-9050 jobs:

```
grep 9050 /var/log/cups/page_log
```

You might have to edit `cupsd.conf` and change the default ´`PageLogFormat` before the log files start being populated.

Comment: I tried cat /var/log/cups/page_log but it's empty...

Comment: It means you haven't printed anything lately and/or it has been rotated in the mean time.  Unzip /var/log/cups/page_log.1.gz and look there...

Comment: Hmm, there is no such file or directory...

Comment: This is what's in the directory
    access_log       access_log.4.gz  error_log       error_log.4.gz  page_log
access_log.1.gz  access_log.5.gz  error_log.1.gz  error_log.5.gz
access_log.2.gz  access_log.6.gz  error_log.2.gz  error_log.6.gz
access_log.3.gz  access_log.7.gz  error_log.3.gz  error_log.7.gz

Comment: `sudo ls /var/log/cups/page*`?

Comment: The output is 
`/var/log/cups/page_log`
when I do cat /var/log/cups/page_log, it shows that it's empty.

Comment: There must be something wrong with your CUPS install.  I would advise you to [ask another question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) and mention that `page_log` is empty but `lpstat -W completed` does work.  I've verified on 2 machines and the answer has been upvoted so someone thought it was helpful, so I can't help you with this new problem.

Comment: By default `PageLogFormat` is set to empty in `cupsd.conf` resulting into no updates made to page_log file.

Comment: @reddot Thank you.  Comment incorporated into answer.  Feel free to [edit] and clarify more.